# How do I make cells have hrefs in an AG Grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

Using Angular 5 and AG GRID, how do I make cells have HREF?
 Im using the example provided here:
[ag-Grid Reference: Getting Started with Angular](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-getting-started/)

For example, I would like the 'Make' column to have an href to an edit page.
It looks like the key is utilizing cell renderers.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/AcfU8spNR4C5gwWu4vtw
Pay attention to dynamic.component.ts and how the module imports ` AgGridModule.withComponents(...)`

Comment: @bc1105, providng me a link to what was already in the ag grid docs doesnt help. Whats needed is a clear example of just a single column with an href, which is not what you provided.

Answer (score 1):

I created a plunkr with *only* the link cell renderer component:
https://plnkr.co/edit/AcfU8spNR4C5gwWu4vtw

Check out the `LinkComponent` and how its imported an used in `DynamicComponent`.

Though it's a simple component in which you may think a function will suffice, I recommend using separate components for every cell renderer as you never know if you will need to scale out.

Comment: the link you provided above is the same link you provided in the comment. Did you forget to get the new URL?

Comment: No I edited the plunkr. Should have different files.